# PySpark 2.4.4 got A JNI error problem with ipython 3.7

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I download the latest Spark, and just changed little in config.

the change in spark-env.sh:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/data/software/miniconda3/bin/ipython
```

When I run `pyspark` it raised error as below.
Error Logs:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file /data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/shell.py:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py in _exec_file(self, fname, shell_futures)
    338                                                  self.shell.user_ns,
    339                                                  shell_futures=shell_futures,
--> 340                                                  raise_exceptions=True)
    341         finally:
    342             sys.argv = save_argv

/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in safe_execfile(self, fname, exit_ignore, raise_exceptions, shell_futures, *where)
   2716                 py3compat.execfile(
   2717                     fname, glob, loc,
-> 2718                     self.compile if shell_futures else None)
   2719             except SystemExit as status:
   2720                 # If the call was made with 0 or None exit status (sys.exit(0)

/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py in execfile(fname, glob, loc, compiler)
    186     with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    187         compiler = compiler or compile
--> 188         exec(compiler(f.read(), fname, 'exec'), glob, loc)
    189 
    190 # Refactor print statements in doctests.

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/shell.py in <module>
     36     SparkContext.setSystemProperty("spark.executor.uri", os.environ["SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI"])
     37 
---> 38 SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
     39 
     40 try:

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    314         with SparkContext._lock:
    315             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 316                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    317                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    318 

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     44     :return: a JVM gateway
     45     """
---> 46     return _launch_gateway(conf)
     47 
     48 

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in _launch_gateway(conf, insecure)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

In [1]: exit                                                                                                                                                                                    
dennis@device2:/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/conf$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
dennis@device2:/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/conf$ export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
dennis@device2:/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/conf$ pyspark 
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file /data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/shell.py:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py in _exec_file(self, fname, shell_futures)
    338                                                  self.shell.user_ns,
    339                                                  shell_futures=shell_futures,
--> 340                                                  raise_exceptions=True)
    341         finally:
    342             sys.argv = save_argv

/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in safe_execfile(self, fname, exit_ignore, raise_exceptions, shell_futures, *where)
   2716                 py3compat.execfile(
   2717                     fname, glob, loc,
-> 2718                     self.compile if shell_futures else None)
   2719             except SystemExit as status:
   2720                 # If the call was made with 0 or None exit status (sys.exit(0)

/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py in execfile(fname, glob, loc, compiler)
    186     with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    187         compiler = compiler or compile
--> 188         exec(compiler(f.read(), fname, 'exec'), glob, loc)
    189 
    190 # Refactor print statements in doctests.

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/shell.py in <module>
     36     SparkContext.setSystemProperty("spark.executor.uri", os.environ["SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI"])
     37 
---> 38 SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
     39 
     40 try:

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    314         with SparkContext._lock:
    315             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 316                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    317                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    318 

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     44     :return: a JVM gateway
     45     """
---> 46     return _launch_gateway(conf)
     47 
     48 

/data/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in _launch_gateway(conf, insecure)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

### Environment:

Java:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

The Spark version is : `park-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop`

The Hadoop is `3.0.0 (CDH-6.2.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the exception happened not because of `ipython 3.7`, is because Spark can't find this class `org.slf4j.Logger` in the class path when `SparkContext` is being initialised (during the the launch of `pyspark` in this case).

According to your description, you are using a "hadoop free" build of Spark while Spark is depending on `Hadoop` thus you need to explicitly tell Spark where to get Hadoop's package jars according to Spark's documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html and I think the class we mentioned above is somehow bounded with those jars thus Spark failed to find it.

You can try two solutions:

1. try to update `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` in `spark-env.sh` to explicitly tell Spark where to find Hadoop related jars if you have Hadoop in your machine.
2. try use this build `spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` in case you don't have Hadoop in your machine. In this build, Hadoop related jars are already put together with Spark, so you should not worry about this problem.

Comment: I use CDH6.2, so I tried to add `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/client` in `spark-env.sh`, but it still didn't work. could you tell me what content should I set for `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH`.

Comment: can you try with `export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)` ? The `hadoop classpath` command is suppose to return you the classpath of hadoop.

Comment: my pleasure to help you ^_^